# Tracking clicks on a button

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, event-tracking

I am trying to track the number of clicks on a button on a Wordpress site. the button is located on the header and it links to an external site. Is there a quick way of doing this? Google's In-Page analytics is not showing any activity on the button

HTML for button:

```
<div class="slogan">
   <a href="isprojectsolutions.homedepot.com/…; target="_blank" class=" button alternative-1 medium" rel="slides[buttonlightbox]">Contact for FREE Consultation</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have tried using, and the results of what you have tried, and also the code that you are trying to track? SO is mainly for coding questions, so it would be helpful for you to post your code.

Comment: I am not sure if this is helpful at all but this is the html for the button:

<div class="slogan">
                
                <a href="https://isprojectsolutions.homedepot.com/homedepot.com~dc~ca~lm~ins~ui~web~mod/IS?lang=EN&storeNum=7001" target="_blank" class=" button alternative-1 medium" rel="slides[buttonlightbox]">Contact for FREE Consultation</a>
                
                </div>

Comment: Can you share the link to your site, with the button you are trying to track?

Comment: http://www.peakinstallations.com

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add an onclick handler that sends to GA an event hit whenever it is clicked:

```
<a href="..." target="_blank" class=" button alternative-1 medium" rel="slides[buttonlightbox]" onclick="ga('send','event','some_category','some_action','some_label');">Contact for FREE Consultation</a>
```

and you can customise the category, action, and label.

Comment: Is this something that I need to set up on Google Analytics as well? Sorry I am new at these tracking things...

Comment: No, you would just need to add the code to the link, and then when triggered, you should be able to see the event in your standard reports (note that you need to wait at 24 hours for data to appear, but you can check in your real-time reports immediately though). Nothing needs to be done in GA.

Comment: No problem, if this is working for you, then please close off this post.